# How to sort array by divisor sum faster?

Tags: performance, c, array, sorting

I am sorting an array by divisor sum in ascending order. If two or more numbers have the same sum of divisors they have to be sorted in ascending order. The problem I have is that my version is not fast enough. Here is my code:

```
int divisorSum( double number )
{
    double sum = number + 1;
    for( int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++ )
        if(( int )number % i == 0 )
            sum += i;
    return sum;
}
void sortByDivisorSum( double *array, int length )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = i + 1; j < length; j++ )
        {
            if(( divisorSum( array[ i ]) > divisorSum( array[ j ])) || (( divisorSum( array[ i ] ) == divisorSum( array[ j ])) && ( array[ i ] > array[ j ])))
            {
                array[ i ] += array[ j ];
                array[ j ] = array[ i ] - array[ j ];
                array[ i ] -= array[ j ];
            }
        }
    }
}
void readArrayy(double *array, int length)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        scanf("%lf", &array[index]);
}
int main( void )
{
    int length, in;
    scanf( "%d", &length );
    double ar[ length ];
    readArrayy( ar, length );
    sortByDivisorSum( ar, length );
    for( in = 0; in < length; in++ )
    {
        printf( "%.0lf ", ar[in]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to solve this in a faster way?

Input:

```
10
24 46 11 36 48 35 27 28 49 6
```

Output:

```
6 11 27 35 28 49 24 46 36 48
```

Comment: Use a fast sorting algorithm, something along the lines of quicksort. If you do not want to implement this yourself, use `std::sort`, which will be reasonably fast.

Comment: @BenSteffan except that `std::sort` is in C++, and the question is tagged [tag:c] ;-)

Comment: @janos Oh my, what a blunder.  Note to self: Next time, read question tags properly.

Answer (score 2):

Many elements of this code can be much faster.

Calculating the sum of divisors will be faster if you:

- Iterate until `sqrt(number)` instead of `number / 2`, and include divisor pairs (`i` and `number / i`)
- Change the type of `number` from `double` to `int`

(See also my review of your [related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/164847/12390).)

Use a faster sorting algorithm, for example quicksort or merge sort.
And when you, avoid mistakes like `if(( divisorSum( array[ i ]) > divisorSum( array[ j ])) || (( divisorSum( array[ i ] ) == divisorSum( array[ j ])) && ( array[ i ] > array[ j ])))`, which recomputes the sum of divisors twice for `array[i]` and `array[j]`.
You could store the results of expensive operations in a variable,
and then you can use that variable multiple times in conditions.

Comment: I agree with storing expensive operations in variables and to iterate to `sqrt( number )`, but: I can't change `double` to `int` because array elements value is in range `0-100.000.000`

Comment: @Timʘtei you haven't mention that constraint in the question. But I don't see how it matters. According to [limits.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h), `INT_MAX` is easily high enough for your needs.

Comment: You are right. I do not know why I was thinking that INT_MAX is about `2.000.000`. Thanks!

Comment: @Timʘtei maybe because it's about `2.000.000.000`, a couple of zeros difference ;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, INT_MAX=2,147,483,647 is a "typical" value and the C standard only requires that is at least 32,767 (but 16-bit integers probably are used only on embedded systems or other special platforms). An alternative is  use types like `int32_t`from `<stdint.h>`.